# Сброс всех данных при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! У меня есть несколько Activity, одно из них - активити с настройками приложения, которое я создаю. В настройках я создал кнопку, при нажатии на которую должны сброситься все настройки приложения, в том числе и все shared preferences, которые содержатся в разных Activity. Реализован такой способ

public class Settings extends MainActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    View view = findViewById(R.id.buttonReset);
    if (view != null) {
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
    clearData(Settings.this);
    }
    });
    }
}

 public static void delete(File file, boolean deleteDir) 
 {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File f : files) {
                    delete(f, true);
                }
            }
            if (deleteDir) {
                file.delete();
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
        }
  }

 public static void clearData(Context context) 
 {
        File files = context.getDir("tmp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        delete(files.getParentFile(), false);
 }
```

}

Настройки удаляются,т.к. в настройках смартфона во вкладке "Управление приложениями" в настройках приложения в строке "Данные" стоит 0.00Б. То есть данные удалены. НО все shared preferences почему-то не удалились. То есть весь прогресс игры (уровни, монеты и тд) сохранился, т.к. он содержится в shared preferences. Подскажите, что я делаю не так. И есть ли другой способ решить проблему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Получите SharedPreferences, у этого объекта вызовите метод edit(). Вам вернётся Editor. У него вызовите метод clear(). После этого у Editor вызовите commit().

Comment: Это конечно работает, но только для одного файла preferences. А у меня их в приложении куча. Нужно удалить все.

Comment: @Alex Les удалением каталога с настройками вы ничего не добьетесь, поскольку настройки останутся в памяти приложения и при первом же удобном случае они будут сохранены на диске. Придется открывать каждый `SharedPreferences` и чистить врукопашную

Comment: Это с помощью intents надо будет добираться до других Activity, чтобы чистить SharedPreferences? т.к. из акстивити настроек нельзя все SharedPreferences почистить. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Alex Les, а зачем Вы у каждого Activity отдельные Preferences используете? Используйте конструкцию PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context) и храните там. Удобно потом будет и очищать их.

Comment: Хм, я об этом не знал, спасибо за совет. Сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Lucky_spirit, извините, но не могли бы Вы показать на примере, как использовать эту конструкцию. Например, мне нужно хранить там несколько файлов Preferences, потом обращаться к ним в других Activity по отдельности.

Comment: @Alex Les файл будет один, зачем вам несколько?

Comment: @Alex Les, к сожалению, в SharedPreferences можно хранить только простые типы данных (int, String, double, boolean). Вам придётся реализовать getter и setter для своих классов Score, Level.